# How to stop goroutine blocked by external I/O started for process?

Tags: go, pipe, exec, goroutine

I'm having a problem here that I can't exit goroutine safely.

I'm having an external process created using exec.Command (storing cmd, stdin pipe and stdout pipe of the process):

```
exec.Command(args[0], args[1]...) // args[0] is a base command
```

Whenever there is a need to start that process I'm calling:

```
cmd.Start()
```

Then upon start and attaching I'm running 2 goroutines:

```
shutdown := make(chan struct{})
// Run the routine which will read from process and send the data to CmdIn channel
go pr.cmdInRoutine()
// Run the routine which will read from CmdOut and write to process
go pr.cmdOutRoutine()
```

cmdInRoutine:

```
func (pr *ExternalProcess) cmdInRoutine() {
    app.At(te, "cmdInRoutine")

    for {
        println("CMDINROUTINE")
        select {
        case <-pr.shutdown:
            println("!!! Shutting cmdInRoutine down !!!")
            return
        default:
            println("Inside the for loop of the CmdInRoutine")
            if pr.stdOutPipe == nil {
                println("!!! Standard output pipe is nil. Sending Exit Request !!!")
                pr.ProcessExit <- true
                close(pr.shutdown)
                return
            }

            buf := make([]byte, 2048)

            size, err := pr.stdOutPipe.Read(buf)
            if err != nil {
                println("!!! Sending exit request from cmdInRoutine !!!")
                pr.ProcessExit <- true
                close(pr.shutdown)
                return
            }

            println("--- Received data for sending to CmdIn:", string(buf[:size]))
            pr.CmdIn <- buf[:size]
        }

    }
}
```

cmdOutRoutine:

```
func (pr *ExternalProcess) cmdOutRoutine() {
    app.At(te, "cmdOutRoutine")

    for {
        select {
        case <-pr.shutdown:
            println("!!! Shutting cmdOutRoutine down !!!")
            return
        case data := <-pr.CmdOut:
            println("Received data for sending to Process: ", data)
            if pr.stdInPipe == nil {
                println("!!! Standard input pipe is nil. Sending Exit Request !!!")
                pr.ProcessExit <- true
                return
            }

            println("--- Received input to write to external process:", string(data))
            _, err := pr.stdInPipe.Write(append(data, '\n'))
            if err != nil {
                println("!!! Couldn't Write To the std in pipe of the process !!!")
                pr.ProcessExit <- true
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Interesting cases here:

1) When process sends EOF (don't mind the **pr.ProcessExit <- true** I was notifying to the parent handler using a channel to stop and exit the process) in **cmdInRoutine** I'm closing the shutdown channel too and this lets **cmdOutRoutine** to exit because inside the select statement there's no default case so it blocks and waits for either exit or data in which then gets written to the running process using stored **stdInPipe**.

2) When I want to just stop goroutines but leave process running i.e kind of pausing the read and write I'm closing the shutdown channel with the hope that those 2 goroutines will end.
   
- **cmdOutRoutine** prints **!!! Shutting cmdOutRoutine down !!!** because select doesn't have default case and closing the shutdown channel causes returning almost immediately
   
- **cmdOutRoutine** doesn't print anything and I'm having a weird feeling that it's not even returning, I think because **It's blocked in the default case at reading from stdInPipe**.

I was thinking of running another goroutine inside the **cmdOutRoutine** before the for loop and have **stdIn** data of the process converted into a channel then I would be able to eliminate default case in **cmdInRoutine** but this creates another problem, that new goroutine also has to be stopped it will still be blocked by the reading from the **stdIn** of the running process.

Any ideas how can I resolve this (modify the logic) to meet the needs of shutting down anytime and starting goroutines (process I/O) but not the running process itself? Or Is there a way to avoid blocking calls of read and write at all, that I'm not aware of yet?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have two separate routines running, you should use two separate shutdown channels. Having just one like you do, you have no idea which one will collect the shutdown signal from the channel first, leaving the other to block.

Comment: Also note that a command cannot be reused after it is run https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd

Comment: @RayfenWindspear it's fine to use a single shutdown channel. A read from a closed channel will always return the zero value immediately, so both goroutines will collect the shutdown signal.

Comment: Ah yes, he is using `close`. I was confusing `pr.ProcessExit` with `pr.shutdown`.  Still, the point has validity if not using close, just isn't the case here.

Comment: Here is an example of the solution you kind of suggested, but yes, you still get the case where the go routine reading from io still has no idea when to stop. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/lRA8S3bv9BM

Comment: @RayfenWindspear I'm calling it's start method, not Run, Output or CombinedOutput, I read about closing channel here: [Closing Multiple Goroutines Simultaneously](http://www.godesignpatterns.com/2014/04/exiting-multiple-goroutines-simultaneously.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably blocked at `pr.stdOutPipe.Read(buf)`. You could try closing `pr.stdOutPipe`, that should interrupt the Read.

You can also close `pr.stdInPipe`, to make sure the Write doesn't block.

**Edit**: This won't allow you to reattach, but there's no other way to interrupt that read. It's probably better to just keep these two goroutines running for the entire process, and pause somewhere else in the stack (e.g. if you don't want to receive the command's output in the paused state, don't write `buf` to `pr.CmdIn` - but be careful to avoid race conditions).

Close might be buggy in current versions of go: [issue 6817](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6817).

**End of edit**

Also, be careful with `pr.CmdIn`. If closing `stdOutPipe` doesn't cause Read to return an error, `cmdInRoutine` will try to write to the channel. If nothing reads from it, `cmdInRoutine` will block forever. I would move `pr.stdOutPipe.Read(buf)` out of the select, then add `pr.CmdIn <- buf[:size]` as another case to the select:

```
func (pr *ExternalProcess) cmdInRoutine() {
    app.At(te, "cmdInRoutine")

    // this check should probably only happen once.
    // if stdOutPipe can change during the loop,
    // then that's a race condition.
    if pr.stdOutPipe == nil {
        println("!!! Standard output pipe is nil. Sending Exit Request !!!")
        pr.ProcessExit <- true
        close(pr.shutdown)
        return
    }

    for {
        println("CMDINROUTINE")
        // we need to allocate a new buffer in each iteration,
        // because when we pass it through the channel,
        // we can no longer safely overwrite the data in it,
        // since the other goroutine might still be using it.
        buf := make([]byte, 2048)
        size, err := pr.stdOutPipe.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            println("!!! Sending exit request from cmdInRoutine !!!")
            // Be careful with this, if you also closed pr.shutdown when you closed stdOutPipe, then this is going to panic (closing a closed channel).
            pr.ProcessExit <- true
            close(pr.shutdown)
            return
        }

        // now that we have some data, try to send it,
        // unless we're done.
        select {
        case <-pr.shutdown:
            println("!!! Shutting cmdInRoutine down !!!")
            return
        case pr.CmdIn <- buf[:size]:
            println("--- Received data for sending to CmdIn:", string(buf[:size]))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking he didn't want to close the pipes. He mentioned pausing the `cmd` by shutting off the goroutines, so I assumed closing them wasn't an option. My two cents. I like the put in channel case, great idea.

Comment: @user1431317 Thanks for the answer. At first I had buffer outside of for loop but then the data (bytes) were mixed from I think contiguous reads. I'm not sure how **buf[:]** behaves just yet. I'm going to try this and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @user1431317 Buffer outside the loop cause mix of data from contiguous reads. Is there anything I can do about this? I don't want to be allocating in for loop. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you're passing the original buffer through the channel, so the goroutine reading from the channel will be using the same buffer, which can be overridden by the next Read in cmdInRoutine.

So you can't avoid allocation unfortunately.

Comment: @user1431317 Would the other way be to copy data byte by byte?

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to do it before the channel send, so there's basically no difference (you could only copy size bytes, but that wouldn't make much of a difference).